# MySQL not starting in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

MySQL does not start in XAMPP. I get no error message, it just says "Starting MySQL Database...". And then nothing, it just stops without saying that it stops or why. And yes i have tried changing the port number. I have searched so much on the internet about this, so if someone knows how to fix this problem, you are a god.

Comment: check that mysql port is blocking using Netstat in xampp

Comment: the most common reason is blocked port, try switch it or check the firewall settings.